# Where I get trial SSL certificate(for testing) on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate, production

I need to test PayPal functions on production, so I need SSL certificate.

I found sites providing SSL certificate, but when I was choosing web platform - cloud platform wasn't there.

Can anyone tell site which can help me ?

Please share experience : what problems could be with including SSL certificates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Heroku (cedar) applications will work on SSL by default these days, so if you have `http://myapp.herokuapp.com` then it will also work on `https://myapp.herokuapp.com` so if you're happy using the herokuapp.com then you don't need to purchase one for testing purposes.